# Zend Subform tutorial displaying forms in unaccurate order

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-sub-form

I implemented the zend subform tutorial from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html) and the problem im having is on occassion it will display the second subform before the first. any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a brief look at the tutorial I would guess the session has not been cleared and still contains form data.